# Find date ranges between large gaps and ignore smaller gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column of a mostly continous unique dates in ascending order. Although the dates are mostly continuos, there are some gaps in the dates of less than 3 days, others have more than 3 days.

I need to create a table where each record has a start date and an end date of the range that includes a gap of 3 days or less. But a new record has to be generated if the gap is longer than 3 days.

so if dates are:

```
    1/2/2012
    1/3/2012
    1/4/2012
    1/15/2012
    1/16/2012
    1/18/2012
    1/19/2012
```

I need:

```
    1/2/2012      1/4/2012
    1/15/2012     1/19/2012
```

Comment: @DanzaiVer Really? That's your contribution to StackOverflow? That's your contribution for expanding the knowledge here that later to be used by others? 

If your post does not contained idea, useful link or additional question to the topic, it is not useful. So, keep it for yourself, and reduce the "flood" that is stored in the SO database.

Comment: @gotqn Aren't you also adding to the flood? because of your blabbering? I'm asking for what did he tried or done so far so that i can add up on what he's doing, SO isn't your Teacher that will spoon feed the answers to you.

Comment: SO is a place where you can find answers without the need to be taught. What you are asking from him is exactly what his teacher will ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
WITH CTE_Source AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT) RN
    FROM dbo.Table1
)
,CTE_Recursion AS 
(
    SELECT *, 1 AS Grp 
    FROM CTE_Source
    WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT src.*, CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD,3,rec.DT) < src.DT THEN rec.Grp + 1 ELSE Grp END AS Grp
    FROM CTE_Source src
    INNER JOIN CTE_Recursion rec ON src.RN = rec.RN +1 
)   
SELECT 
MIN(DT) AS StartDT, MAX(DT) AS EndDT 
FROM CTE_Recursion
GROUP BY Grp
```

First CTE is just to assign continuous numbers for all rows in order to join them later. Then using [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can join on each next row assigning groups if date difference is larger than 3 days. In the end just group by grouping column and select desired results.

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/399ab/1)**

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error saying the number of recursions are too large. I have 320k records.

Comment: @JohnSmith Add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at the end of query to allow for unlimited recursions